# What is the best way of implementing Log like structure in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to implement datetime ordered entity in appengine, pretty much like Appengine's own logs. So I probably will need some kind of unique ordered id generation algorithm.

Has anyone got any suggestion on this?

Comment: You really only have a timestamp to work with.  You can also use the log system, if the data is only kept for a while, and then you re-process it.

Comment: @husayt - you should explain what you are trying to achieve. Then we might be able to provide a solution.

Comment: @PeterKnego Buy default auto generated ids are random evenly scattered numbers. How would you achieve ordered ids to be used for entities on Appengine?

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar need I passed a long integer time stamp as identifier to the Entity constructor.  The identifier can be only a string or a long integer according to [Java Datastore Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities).  In order to see the actual dates and times in the Datastore Viewer I put the same value converted to a java.util.Date into an unindexed property as well.  Admittedly some denormalized redundancy but convenient in practice.

Comment: Oops I ignored uniqueness. A long int time is milliseconds in the Unix epoch. Duplicates never arose here but conceivably could. I suggest representing the time in microseconds, nanoseconds or picoseconds. No time source in GAE is that precise but if two events shared the same time it might work to distinguish them with synthetic submillisecond values. Unique times at the moment of logging would be slow (locking etc). Instead a background task could scan and fix newly written time stamps, sacrificing short term consistency in the interest of better temporal availability (Brewer's CAP theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Use the date that you are appending. One way is to convert it to unix time (ms since 1970) so its numeric.
A better way but more code is to not use the datastore and use bigquery instead. Probably cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

We need more informations about what you want to do.

If you want to make some logs, you can use timestamp indeed.
With python and ndb it's easy :

```
class Log(ndb.Model):
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    message = ndb.StringProperty()
```

Then you order your logs by the date field.
If you want to make like AppEngine, you can link your log with a parent key and order by date and parent key.

[AppEngine Python ndb](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Date_and_Time)

I hope it helped you.